# How can I download configs and assets on first run in my react native application?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a game using react native, and I need to have a loading screen in start of application to download latest app configs and assets such as images, fonts,... . I'm wondering how can I achieve that?
is there any library that can help me?
I read about "rn-fetch-blob" and "react-native-fs", are these the only ways? I don't want to get users permission for assets which are going to be used only in my application.

if you cloud please help me with your advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote database like FireBase (Firestore) to handle all your configurations, Paths ... etc

You can follow this tutorial to setup FireStore in your application 
https://medium.com/react-native-training/firebase-sdk-with-firestore-for-react-native-apps-in-2018-aa89a67d6934

Hopefully this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually I need to download stuff first to use it later in my app. and also it should work offline, for example I have a box in my application which contains different vectors and logos. I need to download these objects first at the start of my application and then show them in appropriate places.

Comment: You can do this as well with firestore offline mode. Also there is more simple way to download the information from firestore then save the information locally using something like “react-native-simple-store” to fetch it locally